What is Newton's second law really saying?
I never really understood what $F = ma$ meant in high school. But now that I'm in university, I was introduced to "Introduction to Mechanics" by K&K. Although I sense that I've truly grasped the concept, there's a small problem which is bothering me. I want to know if my understanding is correct, and, if it is, how I can address the problem I'm facing.
So, say we take a string and accelerate a block with it at some standard length on a sheet of ice. We see that the block accelerates at $a_1$. Then, we take another block and find that it accelerates at $a_2$.
These are the accelerations always measured when we pull on the block with the same standard length of the string. No matter where the experiment is done, the blocks accelerate with the same magnitudes. This suggests that the blocks have an intrinsic property to resist motion. The greater this property in a block, the lower its acceleration.
So, we wish to create a scale that quantifies the notion of resisting motion. So, we ascribe a quantity called "mass" to each body. Say a particular block accelerates at $a_0$. We ascribe an arbitrary mass, $m_0$ to it. Then we create a linear, relative scale that ascribes a mass of $m$ for any other object that accelerates at an acceleration of $a$:
$$m := \frac{a_0}{a}m_0$$
As you can see, mass is inversely proportional to the acceleration it experiences in this scale. Now, suppose  we measure the accelerations of a bunch of blocks relative to a reference block and label the mass $m$ on each block. So we have a bunch of different mass blocks.
Now, I measure the acceleration of each block when pulling on them by a standard length of string. On the x-axis I plot the block's mass and on the y-axis, I plot its acceleration. Obviously, you get the curve $a = k/m$ where the value of $k$ depends on the original reference mass. Along the curve $a = k/m$, you're applying the "same action" on each block because you're pulling with the same standard length of string. It's just that you're varying the mass of the block and seeing how its acceleration is varying. This curve can be described by $k = ma$. Since the action is same throughout the curve, the action is described by $ma$. Hence, it's reasonable to define the force to be $ma$.
Notice that none of this had any new physical content. It's just that you've defined mass and, from it, defined force. From what I gather, the only real physical law is the fact that forces can be superposed vectorially.
But this would mean that a non-linear definition of $m$, although clunky, shouldn't be problematic:
$$m := \frac{a_0^2}{a^2}m_0$$
For this definition of mass, $a = k/\sqrt{m}$, which would mean that the force is described by $F = \sqrt{m}a$. This should be fine, technically speaking. But, Gregory's Classical mechanics offers a completely different view:

if mass were defined in this way, then the mass of a multi-particle system  would not be equal to the sum of the masses of its constituent particles. This is not contradictory, but a very undesirable feature and explains why the standard definition is used

Why is this true? And are there any other undesirable features that make the standard definition a wise choice?

Did you mean $m=\frac{a_0^2}{a^2}m$?

@J.G. yes, my bad, I'll make the edit

I will not defend high school teaching of physics; while there are good teachers who try hard, there is a lot of places on this Earth where the teaching is atrocious. I will also not attack you that you used "action", which is unfortunate because later in university physics there will be an important quantity that has that name. However, it is completely unacceptable that you are already in university and yet you have "standard length of string" giving you "acceleration". That signifies that your concepts are still all haywire. You aren't that far off in the rest of the post, but this was bad.

I'm someone who enjoys dabbling with non-standard interpretations of physics.  Having done this a lot (typically for fun), I would strongly encourage you not to do so until you have a very strong understanding of standard physics.  Typically upon a very small definition like this we build gargantuan models, such as those capable of modeling bridge and skyscrapers, and bring in all sorts of new ways of looking at the math (naturallyInconsistent alludes to one major one with the comment about "action").

It will be very hard to grasp why the standard definitions are useful if you first learn all of the undesirable ways to do it.  That approach takes forever.  For example, consider calculus itself, at the heart of physics.  We quite literally spent thousands of years trying to figure out how to make it work, with countless failures, before we finally came across the right one through Newton and Leibnitz.  Some of their failure modes are quite subtle and take a long time to understand.  And in the end, the one that works is the most useful.

@naturallyInconsistent could you elaborate on why referring to standard length of string giving acceleration is bad. Maybe that's not the best way to express, but what I meant to say is a string that is stretched to a certain length gives a certain acceleration. The same force is applied when I pull on another block with this same "standard length" of extension. This is precisely the argument given in K&K. If not, could you point out where our arguments differ

@Aryaan Typically in introductory texts, strings, ropes, and wires are assumed to be "ideal" with no stretch.  Springs have a stretch and a spring stretched a given displacement away from its equilibrium will indeed have useful properties (the ones you specify).  It sounds like the source you are referencing is starting with Hooke's law (from before Newton).  It is a valid historical way to think about it, but a tricky one unless one starts by doing a few dozen different experiments with the spring to arrive at an agreement that Hooke;s law is accurate for that spring.

And idealness is tricky with this starting point.  Real springs are not ideal, and that non-idealness can obscure the thought experiments where you drag the blocks around.  And, indeed, the typical modern phrasing of Hooke's law is phrased in terms of Force, not the other way around. (historical physics is a fascinating topic.  It's not as linear as I used to think!)

@CortAmmon I provide an argument borrowed from K&K. "If we move our hand ahead of the rider so that the rubber band is always stretched to the same standard length, we find that...the rider moves with constant acceleration" and "suppose we try the same experiment with a different rider...the same rubber band stretched to the standard length produces a constant acceleration, but the acceleration is different from the first case"

That phrasing (with a rubber band) feels a lot safer than phrasing it about a standard string.  I recommend sticking to the rubber band wording until you get deep into material properties (at which point strings do stretch).  One thing you may find tricky with that image, however, is that it is remarkably hard to get a rubber band to stay at the same length without using something to fix its length, like a stick placed between the ends of the band.  Fixing its length in this way would destroy the entire test, so make sure your mind doesn't try to do it that way.  Instead, I think you're ...

... assumign there is a feedback loop used to adjust one endpoint to keep the length the same.  This would historically be implemented by a human being trying to make this work.  If you can visualize a scientist in their lab, carefully pulling blocks around on a frictionless surface using a rubber band, then you will indeed reach the key philosophical insight that there is something constant about what the rubber band is doing to the block.

So in that sense you can make sense of Newton's laws that way.  It's just a bit harder, and tied rather tightly to the idea of your spring.  When you add Newton's 3rd law, then you get the full insight: that it's not just springs that have this behavior. Everything does it, including other blocks, and the 3rd law give you the mathematical tool needed to calculuate the results.

I think I now know enough about what you are asking to venture an answer (a comment, since the question is closed).  In a very general sense, the "undesirable" behaviors are things which get in the way of calculuation.  If you have one way of thinking (such as $F=ma$) which lets you predict how a system moves lines of math, and another one (such as $F\sqrt m a$) which lets you do the same prediction with 10 pages of complicated algebraic manipulation, we'll want to use the former.

@CortAmmon yes, I suppose I should have used rubber bands instead of strings. Nevertheless, I don't see why that's a good enough reason to close the question based on lack of clarity when I've clearly explained my question regarding Gregory's comment

And as a specific example, targetting calcuulus, the typical definition of an integral is additive in nature.  Phrasing things in a way which permits adding up infintessimal pieces makes it so that we can apply integrals.  If we have to combine them in another way, we need a slightly different tool.

I didn't VTC, so I can't say for sure what others thought.  My instinct when I read this question  (and after getting over the string/rubber-band thing) was "oh wow, this is a gigantic question that you could easily write a 400 page thesis about, satisfying a history of science P.h.D."  Listing all of the undesirable features of an approach is not a small feat, and involves digging into the hundreds of years of physics built on top of F=ma

The math is way too complicated to study at an introductory level, but the "action" that naturallyInconsistent mentioned is part of exactly such an argument.  They found the choices made for F=ma were very inconvenient, and formulated a completely different way to describe the physics called Lagrangian mechanics.  Explaining why this was a good idea is not a small task.

Cort Ammon correctly pointed out that you meant a rubber band rather than a string. I would have suggested a spring instead, as did he. But there is no such thing as a standard rubber band or standard spring either; you can make some arbitrary standard, of course, but that is not what the terms mean. You'll have to be a lot more careful with things if you want to explore outside the standard treatment of physics, or else you will find yourself stuck in some spider hole.

@Aryaan "a non-linear definition of $m$, although clunky, shouldn't be problematic" There is a much bigger problem with your proposal, which is that it isn't even dimensionally correct.
